# Laravel Blade Directive inside {{-blocks

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a custom blade directive for formatting `DateTime`-objects:

```php
$blade->directive('datetime', function ($dateTime) {
    return "<?php echo ($dateTime)->format('Y-m-d\\TH:i:s') ?>";
});
```

This allows me to set a `DateTime`-object in an `datetime-local` `input` tag:

```html
<input
    type="datetime-local"
    name="start_date"
    value="@datetime(now())"
>
```

However, I would like to also use the `old`-method to set the value from the previous request if it exists.
Only if `old('start_date')` returns `null`, I want to call `@datetime`.
The [documentation about blade directives](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#extending-blade) does not show any way to do this.

### What I tried so far

#### Call the directive in PHP

The most obvious solution would be to just call `@datetime` inside the `{{` block.

```html
<input
    type="datetime-local"
    name="start_date"
    value="{{ old('start_date') ?? @datetime(now())"
>
```

This unfortunately does not work because the text inside the `{{`-block is PHP, and PHP does not know what to do with `@datetime`.

#### `Blade::callCustomDirective`

In the `BladeCompiler`-class, I found the method `callCustomDirective`.
Unfortunately though, the method is `protected`, so it leads to an error.

```html
<input
    type="datetime-local"
    name="start_date"
    value="{{ old('start_date') ?? Blade::callCustomDirective('datetime', now()) }}"
>
```

#### Move the directive outside `}}`

I also tried this (without much hope):

```html
<input
    type="datetime-local"
    name="start_date"
    value="{{ old('start_date') ?? }}  @datetime(now())"
>
```

As expected, this leads to a syntax error.

---

If anyone knows how to solve this issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it's blade file, then you can use @directive anywhere in the blade, You don't need to wrap the directive into the {{}}. I think you can use ```{{ old('start_date') }} ?? @datetime(now())```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately, it does not work.
`{{ old('start_date') }} ?? @datetime(now())` just causes the template to write out " ?? 2020-05-23T12:21:21" into the HTML of the `input`-tag.

Comment: You can use something like ```@if(old('start_date')) {{old('start_date')}} @else @datetime(now()) @endif```

Comment: Right! I will use this as a workaround, thank you! So there is probably no way to actually call a blade directive from code?